# C list class like progeram

Tags: c, list, loops, object

I need to simulate a class of Linked list in C.
My problem is with saving information like list length, head, last node and average with each "object" created.
Meaning

```
List *A = ctor()
addItem(A, 0)
```

and checking for list length of A will return 2.
but if I do another list named B, and add two other items it will show 3.
I'm not allowed to use loops in any function (excluding the destructor - no recursion and goto also)
and honestly i cant think of a way to save that information for each "object" (lacking another word for it right now)
Any suggestions?
Everything is in C
I don't want to use simple global variables because I still need to save different information for each instance (found the word)

**EDIT:**

Struct contains:

```
int value
List *next
List *previous
```

and can not contain any more values

**EDIT 2**

I can add more fields to the struct

Requirements are:
Do not use loops, recursion, goto

List functions:

1) Construct -create a new list

2) Destruct - delete all nodes (can use loop in that function)

3) Adding a node

4) Deleting a node - given a pointer to that node

5) Returning the length of the list

6) Return a pointer to the first node

7) Return a pointer to the last node

8) Return a pointer to the next node (given pointer to current one)

9) Return a pointer to the previous node (given pointer to current one)

10) Return value of a node (given a pointer to that node)

11) Return average of values in list

Thats it, the functions are very basic when the instructions are not so

restrictive

I dont know if it helps a lot

Comment: Use a `struct` to contain the needed data. Classes are just `struct`s with automatic constructors/destructors and associated functions.

Comment: "checking for list length of A will return 2". Why? You have added 1 item and the length is 2? Anyway, why can't you just add a counter field inside the `List` structure? And add more fields for whatever other things you need to keep track of.

Comment: Too broad. But do some searching yourself. Keywords might be "object oriented programming in C"

Comment: ctor creates a new list with meaning a new node is added, and another resriction is not having more than value field and next/previous

Comment: @Yarden. That doesn't really make sense. The default `ctor` should create a new list with no items.

Comment: Ehm. No loops, no recursion and no goto? Good luck with that.

Comment: You have `next`. If you really want to count the number of items then just traverse all the `next` pointers. But that requires loops. I'm suspecting either you have misunderstood the requirements or your assignment problem is not well formed.

Comment: @kaylum It is the right requirements though i think i will try adding more fields to the structure, though seems a pretty hard work to synchronize all nodes inside the list (e.g when adding a node all other nodes should add + 1 to their count)

Comment: You told us the other requirement is that you can't add any fields to the struct. Aren't you beginning to see why the requirements as stated by you do not make sense?

Comment: I'm with kaylum on this. Can you provide the literal project requirements? It feels like something is being lost in translation here.

Comment: edited the requirements in the qustion

Comment: Now your two edits are contradictory. Anyway, it still makes no sense. There is no point in having a chain of `next/prev` unless the code will traverse them somewhere. And you cannot traverse a variable length linked list without loops, gotos, recursions, etc. As suggested, it would be better if you pasted the *exact* assignment wording.

Comment: Its not supposed to be easy, those are the definite restrictions.
But i've tried coming up with a way to do this and found none, thats why im here.

Comment: @kaylum Unless you store that information in the struct of each List. So you'd have a field for the length of the list which you increment every time you add a node. And you have a field for the last element, which you use to append the next node to insert and then update after doing so. This shouldn't use any loops, gotos or recursion.

Comment: @Martinn What you are saying may be true if the requirement was worded more narrowly. Like "no loops when creating a new list node". But a blanket "no loops" requirement does not make sense. How would one find a node in the middle? The point is that the requirements are unclear. We will never reach the right solution if we start with the wrong requirements. Is it really that unreasonable to ask the OP to paste in the exact wording of the assignment in context?

Comment: @Martinn Incrementing the counter on one node still won't update the field on other nodes and without loops I don't know how to update all of them

Comment: @kaylum Of course we don't have the exact requirements in front of us, but I suspect that there is no requirement to access information from nodes in the middle of the List, or to insert/delete them. The OP has just mentioned that the length of the list has to be returned, which can be done in the method I described above. If that's not the case then either it's not possible, or there is something else that we're not aware of.

Comment: @kaylum im not trying to interfere people who try to help me
Those are the exact words
No loops - excluding destructor
No goto
No recuresion
That's it, nothing more.

Comment: @Yarden Perhaps there's nothing more in that one sentence. But how about all the sentences that go around it? That is, the full context.

Comment: As asked above, can we have the EXACT (I assume homework) assignment? Scan it? Take a picture with a smartphone while wearing a mask in case we can see your face in a reflective surface? Copy/paste it?

Comment: Thought about trying to save count as a pointer i think that should do it.
And i will translate the other instructions

Comment: Ok, that is clearer. Can you declare your own structures or not? If you can then suggest you have seperate structures for `List` and for `ListNode`. `List` will contain: count, current_average, head, tail. `ListNode` will contain: value, next, prev.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I was assuming that your functions shall only operate with nodes, which is why I hid the list structure from the caller, resulting in this mess of an API.*

---

OK, this is going to win the prize for the worst API, but here's a possible solution:

```
struct node;

struct list {
  int sum;
  size_t count;
  struct node * head, * end;

struct node {
  struct node * next, * previous;
  struct list * list;
  int value;
};

struct node * allocate_list(void) {
  struct node * sentinel = malloc(sizeof(*sentinel));
  struct list * list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
  sentinel->previous = sentinel->next = NULL;
  list->head = list->end = sentinel;
  list->sum = 0;
  list->count = 0;
  sentinel->list = list;
  return sentinel;
}

void free_list(struct node * n) {
  struct list * list = n->list;
  n = list->head;
  while (n != list->end) {
    n = n->next;
    free(n->previous);
  }
  free(n);
  free(list);
}

void add_item(struct node * n, int value) {
  struct node * new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
  new->previous = n->previous;
  n->previous = new;
  new->next = n;
  new->value = value;
  new->list = n->list;
  if (new->previous == NULL) {
    new->list->head = new;
  }
  ++(new->list->count);
  new->list->sum += value;
}
```

The rest of the functions should be trivial, and won't definitely not need any loops or recursions.

The key idea is storing a pointer to data shared for the whole list to each node. This shared data can thus be accessed and modified from any node.

Comment: I took a different approach but thank you for your time!
It did help me

Comment: @Yarden if you want you can share your approach by posting it as an answer. (Answering your item question is OK here)